# Find $p$ if $2p-1$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

I need to find prime numbers $p$ such that $2p-1$ is a perfect square. I tried hard, but could not get a proper solution for this. I could guess $p=13$ works, but I need a proper rigorous solution for this. I cant think of one.

Comment: And $p = 5, 41, 61, 113, 181,$ etc. What exactly are you trying to prove about such $p$?

Comment: Note that $p = 5$ also works as $2p - 1 = 9 = 3^2$.

Comment: This is http://oeis.org/A027862

Answer (score 1):

All primes excluding $2$ and $3$ are of the form $6k\pm 1$. We have that:

$$2(6k+1)-1=12k+1$$
This leads to $$12k=m^2-1$$
$$12k=(m+1)(m-1)$$
$$\to m+1=12a, m-1=\frac ka$$
Or vice versa, subject to $a,k \in \Bbb Z, a|k$

Now use:
$$2(6k-1)-1=12k-3$$
$$\to 12k-4=m^2-1$$
$$\to 4(3k-1)=(m+1)(m-1)$$
Go from there.

Comment: Excluding 2. *And 3*.

Comment: I'm stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[OEIS A027862](http://oeis.org/A027862) lists the primes $p$ of the form $p=n^2+(n+1)^2$.  It remarks that these are the ones where $2p-1$ is a square.  We can show that if $p$ is of this form $2p-1$ is a square because $$2p-1=2(n^2+(n+1)^2)-1=4n^2+4n+1=(2n+1)^2$$